# Extract time from Date Time as a separate column

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My table looks like this -

| DateTime | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-12-01 08:26:00 | 34 |
| 2010-12-01 09:41:00 | 42 |

I want to extract the time from `DateTime` and create a third column of it and then group it with frequency counts. Is there a way to do this in SQL? I'm using Apache Spark with inline SQL. I have achieved the equivalent using Spark functions like this -

```
df2 = df.withColumn('Time', date_format('DateTime', 'HH:mm:ss'))
df3 = df2.groupBy("Time").count() // To get count under every hour
df3.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in SQL, you can do:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
result = spark.sql("select date_format(DateTime, 'HH:mm:ss') as Time, count(*) as cnt from df group by Time")
```